How to show this last condition is equivalent to saying the bilinear form in the proposition is nondegenerate?
I'm reading Lei Fu's "Etale Cohomology Theory".

How to show this last condition is equivalent to saying the bilinear form in the proposition is nondegenerate?

One says (I guess) a bilinear form on a locally free $\mathcal O_S$-module of finite rank $\mathcal A$ is nondegenerate if the induced morphism $\mathcal A \to \mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal O_S}( \mathcal A, \mathcal O_S)$ is an isomorphism.
Locally an an open set where $\mathcal A$ is free, this is equivalent to the determinant of the map (well-defined after choosing a basis) being invertible. Now use the fact that an element of a ring is invertible if and only if it is invertible modulo every prime ideal to see that nondegeneracy is equivalent to nondegeneracy modulo every prime ideal.

Can we deduce $A_{\mathfrak q}\times A_{\mathfrak q}\to B_{\mathfrak q}$ is nondegenerate from $A_{\mathfrak q}/\mathfrak qA_{\mathfrak q}\times A_{\mathfrak q}/\mathfrak qA_{\mathfrak q}\to B_{\mathfrak q}/\mathfrak qB_{\mathfrak q}$ is nondegenerate?

@Borntobeproud Yes, because an element in a local ring being invertible is equivalent to its reduction modulo the maximal ideal being invertible.

But there is another definition of nondegeneracy of $\mathcal A\times\mathcal A\to \mathcal O_S$, that is, for any open set $U\subseteq S$, if there exists some $x\in \mathcal   A(U)$ such that for all $y\in \mathcal A(U)$, we have $\operatorname{Tr}(xy)=0$, then $x=0$. Are these two definitions of nondegeneracy of $\mathcal A\times\mathcal A\to \mathcal O_S$ equivalent in the proposition?

@Borntobeproud No. A ramified covering of curves, i.e. $f\colon \mathbb A^1 \to \mathbb A^1, t\mapsto t^2$, will give a counterexample. The pairing $\operatorname{Tr}(xy)$ takes two polynomials in $t$ (or rational functions, on an open set) to their product after all odd degree terms is removed. As a bilinear form on the free module over $k[t^2]$ with basis $1,t$, this is given by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \ 0 & t^2 \end{pmatrix}$. It's easy to see from this that the bilinear form is nondegenerate in your sense but not mine.
